# Is there a package to convert network() or igraph() networks to Rgraphviz compatible in R?

Tags: r, graphviz, igraph

Spent a lot of time formatting networks in the formats used for analysis in SNA and igraph packages.  Is there a bridge between these and Rgraphviz's desired data-type?  By this, I mean, preserves: Source-to-destination, Label, Edge weight, other attributes like color, etc.

Comment: Hi.What is better igraph or Rgraphviz?

Comment: I prefer igraph, but it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, very easily, and clearly in [the igraph documentation](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/write.graph.html):

```
write.graph(mygraph, file="filename", format="dot")
```

Comment: Is there a solution that does not require writing a file?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any package to do convert `igraph` in `Rgraphviz`, but, this is one way without saving the file. The function `graph::graphAM` receive an ***adjacency Matrix*** which can be got from `igraph` using the function `igraph::get.adjacency`.

With that approach, if you have any feature linked to nodes or edges you will need to add them individually.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create the Data
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                        "Esmeralda"),
                 age=c(48,33,45,34,21),
                 gender=c("F","M","F","M","F"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                           "David", "Esmeralda"),
                    to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                    same.dept=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
                    friendship=c(4,5,5,2,1,1), advice=c(4,5,5,4,2,3))

# Create the igraph object
g <- igraph::graph.data.frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)

# transform igraph object in graph which will be used in Rgraphviz
graph::graphAM(igraph::get.adjacency(g) %>% as.matrix(),
           edgemode = 'directed') %>%
  Rgraphviz::layoutGraph() %>%
  Rgraphviz::renderGraph()
```

[image]